# Batch move files with quotation mark in name

Tags: batch-file

Someone in this forum helped me develop a batch file that moves files from one folder to another folder based on current month as below:

```cmd
::echo You were in %cd% ran from batch file "%~f0"
pushd "%~dp0"
::echo You are in now in %cd%
::popd

::@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
::Set "Dir1=C:\Directory1"
::Set "Dir2=C:\Directory2"

@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Dir1=%cd%"
::echo %Dir1%
set "Dir2=%cd%"
::echo %Dir2%


:: Build Mon[01..12] array
Set Cnt=100
For %%A in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
) Do Set /A Cnt+=1&Set Mon[!Cnt:~-2!]=%%A
::Set Mon[

For /f "delims=" %%A in (
' Dir /B/A-D "%Dir1%\?-??-???? - * - *.pdf" ^|findstr "[01][0-9][0-3]      
[0-9]   20   [0-9][0-9]\.pdf$" '
) Do (
   Set "File=%%~nA"
   Call Set "MoveTo=%Dir2%\!File:~-4!\%%Mon[!File:~-8,2!]%%\"
   MD "!MoveTo!" >Nul 2>&1
   Move "%%~fA" "!MoveTo!"
)

popd
```

This script works great but it is not processing a file with the naming that has the `"` symbol, eg: `'10"'`.

Can someone help me to modify this script to allow this symbol to be processed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31QcN.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show a sample of a `dir` listing showing the filename in question

Comment: In Windows there are no files with a quotation marks in the name!?

Comment: i have included a screen shot of the file names in my original post

Comment: It looks like that is actually `right double quote (”)`

Comment: BTW, you will see this better in the console if you change the font.  The default font for `cmd.exe` renders all 3 double quotes the same.

Answer (score 0):

The extended characters `U+201C` and `U+201D` are allowed in file names.  Ensure your script is UTF8 and try these characters instead.

```
" U+0022 Double quotation mark <= not this one    
“ U+201C Left double quotation mark
” U+201D Right double quotation mark
```